# In the Fat Free Framework $mapper, how can I modify the data in in one field as it is returned from $mapper->get()

Tags: php, object, fat-free-framework

This is a more advanced question on overriding the Mapper class:

- I want to modify data in the `$mapper` prior to its return via the `$mapper->get()` function.
- I only want to do this for one field, not all of them.

I cant seem to wrap my head around this. How can I do this in a mapper model class?

Of course, this is typical mapper usage:

```
$data = new \Models\Whatever;
$data->load('array('dataid=?',$id);
echo $data->get('foo');
echo $data->get('bar');
```

What I want to do is when I am calling `$data->get('bar')` I want to first process the data within the mapper, and output my special data. I want `$data->get('foo')` to return unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can extend the mapper in such a way:

```
class Whatever extends \DB\SQL\Mapper {
  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct( \Base::instance()->get('DB'), 'whatever' );
  }

  // wrap the getter function
  function get($key) {
    $val = parent::get($key);
    if(method_exists($this,'get_'.$key))
      $val = call_user_func(array($this,'get_'.$key),$val);
    return $val;
  }

  // add custom getter
  function get_foo($val) {
    return $val.'bar';
  }
}
```

now your `$mapper->get('foo');` or `$mapper->foo` will be passed throught your custom getter function and appends `bar` to the result string.

Comment: So if I didn't need/want `$mapper->foo` to work, only `$mapper->get('foo');` then I can skip re-declaring `function get($key)` ?

Comment: No. Only works for both or nothing. But you can of cause just create a get_foo method that uses ->get directly and you use that get_foo method where  you need it.